# how to cache external files

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, caching, pagespeed

I tested my website, for Google Page Speed.

I did the cache optimizing in .htaccess, but it doesn't affect files that are from Facebook and Google+

```
Leverage browser caching

http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js (20 minutes)

https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js (30 minutes)

https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/…e:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2 (60 minutes)
```

What can I do for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

There is really nothing you can do at this point.  Besides, the cache timeouts set by those external scripts are set so low on purpose, just in case they need to update them.  If they had a longer cache timeout, updates would take longer to propagate since many people include them in their websites.